# "an error occurred - please retry your request" when I try to accept an answer

Tags: support, accepted-answer, error-message

I've got a bug with regards to accepting answers for a question I asked.

The error is really vague but when I click the tick, it just says

> an error occurred - please retry your request.

The answer + question can be found here: [Jekyll page isn't updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105784/jekyll-page-isnt-updating/36211236#36211236)

Comment: What browser and OS are you on? Any extensions/add-ons/plugs-ins installed?

Comment: @Oded I'm on Chrome Windows 8.1 (I've also tested on Ubuntu Firefox, Edge Windows 10, Chrome Windows 10, Chromium Ubuntu, IE 11 on Windows 8.1), and I'm a web developer, so yes to your second :-)

Comment: Try without any extensions / addons enabled, in that case. Do you see anything in the developer console ? (Especially the network tab ?). I'm inclined to think that it's something on your end or something is wrong with your network. (Firewall ?)

Comment: To add to what @JonasCz said, it could be something like injected content by your ISP/Network Admins/Malicious Proxy, try over https - that will ensure no MITM.

Comment: @Oded thanks, but I just tried it as both incognito and over https. Still not working :-/. I'm on a work PC so disabling any proxies etc. is out of the question.

Comment: OK, next question is - does this also happen when at home, on a different network?

Comment: @Oded Yes my work PC is on Windows 8.1, the other Operating Systems were from my home PC (I also tried disabling my firewall etc.)

Comment: Strange - I can't see your account hitting the favourite route from our logs at all. This suggests that the request isn't hitting our load balancers.

Comment: @Oded so it's something at my end? I just ran it through Fiddler (personal web debugging through a proxy) and there's nothing going through that either... I'll make a Box and try it on that, my OS's are modified for dev tools.

Comment: I'd expect a call to `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36105784/vote/5` - if one isn't made... either the JS is corrupt (unlikely, as you see an error message), or it isn't going through.

Comment: I'll pull it to a local version and run it through a debug session tonight, then post you an answer/comment... Thanks anyway

Comment: Hmm.. weirdly I just got the same thing (on another SE site), although it worked after a page refresh..

Comment: Corporate proxies sometimes cause this problem. It usually corrects itself after a brief time. It seems to be related to delays in the proxy processing the request.

Answer (score 12):

After screwing about with a local version of StackOverflow and debugging, I found out that the issue was down to user error and a similar setup between work and home. The issue wasn't with my PC, but with a proxy that was set up on my home router and a proxy set up on my work PC (can't remove it -.-). See the steps below to recreate (for fixing it):

- Install Cisco AnyConnect
- Set the load balancer to Automatic
- Restart
- StackOverflow is now broken!

And see below for steps on 'fixing it':

- Set Cisco AnyConnect Load balance to manual and set the server location to London (or closest city)
- Ensure you don't have any web filtering services (My work also has ScanSafe, I had to ask them to punch a hole in the filter)
- StackOverflow is now better :-)

I completely forgot about the proxy on my home router, but if you have one enabled, ensure the filtering is off. Mine was set to filter some stuff and the calls just got caught up in that.